# Какой компонент рисует диаграммы в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, диаграммы

Какой компонент рисует диаграммы в Delphi и в какой вкладке он находится?

Comment: и с какие элементы нужны + для работы с этим компонентом?

Answer (score 2):

Компонент `TChart(Chart)`, вкладка `TeeChart`.

В Delphi 2010

Comment: А где в компоненте Tchart выбрать тип диаграммы? Точно не знаю, но вроде как так можно.

Comment: при добавлении серии вроде спрашивает тип диаграмы